# Why were the "proton blasts" causing such problems?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the Voyager episode "Deadlock" Voyager is split into two ships occupying the same space but out of phase with each other. They appear to have split their matter but only one ship (the healthy one) had retained a supply of anti-matter which meant that the anti-proton bursts were only firing in the healthy voyager.

Since the proton bursts were only aimed at the anti-matter, why would the proton bursts from the healthy ship damage the *unhealthy* one?

Why would the proton bursts affect the unhealthy ship if they were sharing the same anti-matter? Which phase was the anti-matter in?

Answer (score 1):

> Why would the proton bursts from the healthy ship damage the unhealthy
>   one?

Because photon bursts go through several rapid phase changes as they decay, normally there is nothing to interact with, however when the photon burst was in phase with Voyager-2 there was a huge amount of matter to react to, causing explosions which damaged Voyager-2.

> Which phase was the anti-matter in?

The antimatter was in regular phase, with Voyager-1

You might ask Why wasn't the anti-matter copied?
All the matter in Voyager-1 was copied/re-created by the anomaly, but only regular matter was created, not the anti-matter (actually antimatter may have been created, but in proportions too small to *matter* (do you see what I did there? :p)).
The asymmetry where enormously different ratios of matter:antimatter are created in natural events is seen also in the big bang, there wasn't a perfect 1:1 matter/antimatter ratio, which would have nullified all matter/antimatter. Instead vastly more regular matter was created in the big bang; cosmologists don't know why . . . *yet*

Comment: This is why I didn't want my questions chopped up, because I went into detail in another question about the phase shifts. If the healthy ship which would be Voy-2 was actually the original ship with the anti matter in phase with it and it was bombarding the anti-matter with the proton bursts. Why would that affect Voy-1 the unhealthy voyager. Why would the proton bursts go through a phase change after the fact as you suggest? And if so why would they have any affect on the other voyager as they were being directed at the anti-matter that was out of phase with it so didn't exist in their phase?

Comment: Your cosmology is wrong. The current theory is that _very slightly_ more matter than antimatter was created in the big bang, and that all the antimatter was annihilated by nearly all of the matter, leaving a tiny bit of left-over matter that is what we see around us today, and a whole lot of photons (the cosmic background radiation).

Comment: @MikeScott interesting. I don't know if you know the whole story about Einstein & Hubble (they actually met). Einstein believed in the static model which was a given at the time even though his theory of relativity proved otherwise. Eventually Hubble proved that it was expanding. Now they're saying with the discovery of dark matter, that maybe it's expanding and contracting. I didn't know there was an accepted version of any cosmology. I thought that different scientist pick which of the four models they like to build their models. Also can you remove the hold on the other question? Thx

Comment: JMFB: Photon busts go through phase changes, because that's what they do. All energy bursts of sufficient intensity will be in a state of phase flux. I am *absolutely 100% certain* of this, because I've just made it up :)